# Can you play two different physical games at the same time with one Nintendo switch account?

Tags: nintendo-switch, nintendo-account

Say Steve owns a Nintendo switch A and also owns a Nintendo switch B.  (One of the other or both machines might be a lite, I don't think it matters.)

Steve owns the physical cartridge of game G and Steve also owns the physical cartridge of game H.

(Completely different games.  NO digital copies involved - physical cartridges for both G and H.)

Steve has one (and only one) paid Nintendo account.

Both machines A and B are logged in as Steve's account (let's say A is the "primary" if it matters).

Cartridge G is in machine A.  Cartridge H is in machine B.

Both machines are 100% online and are never offline.

At 10:05AM Steve picks up machine A and starts playing game G on machine A.

Steve's brother Bill is sitting next to Steve.  At 10:06AM Bill picks up machine B and tries to play game H on machine B.

Is it possible to play **two** completely different physical **cartridge** games, at the **same** time, on **two** switches, both registered to the **one** Nintendo account?

This question is only about

- Switches that are **both completely online always**
- Games that are **only physical cartridges**
- same account, playing at the same time

Surprisingly I could not find the answer to this anywhere including Nintendo.

There are heaps of articles about sharing digital games; about cloud saving; about offline play; and other issues of "one account multiple machines", but not this simpler question.

Comment: My understanding is that the Switch uses substantially the same process as [the PS4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kWSIFh8ICaA), for physical cartridges.

Comment: @Kevin - heh, great video, had not seen it  :)  I appreciate that, cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the same user can be playing different games on different systems.  I've tested this using Breath of the Wild, Mario Kart 8 Deluxe, and Pokemon Sword/Shield.  You can even be playing different physical versions of the same game.

If there's a desire to not have save data be messed with when others play the switch, you can make a guest account for them to use.

Comment: What a great answer - thanks, I'll send a bounty.  Seasons greets